# Image should get changed when message is received in android

Tags: java, android, events

```
    package com.example.nhx;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    ImageView imageView1;
    ImageView imageView2;
    Button ON, OFF;
    String msg = "";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // ---get the SMS message passed in---

        if (msg.contains("LED ON")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "HELLO WORLD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (msg.contains("LED OFF")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (msg == "LED ON") {

            imageView1.setVisibility(imageView1.VISIBLE);
            imageView2.setVisibility(imageView2.INVISIBLE);

        }

        if (msg == "LED OFF") {
            imageView2.setVisibility(imageView2.VISIBLE);
            imageView1.setVisibility(imageView1.INVISIBLE);
        }
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                // str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                // str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += msg;
                // str += "\n";

            }

        }

        if (msg.contains("LED ON")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "HELLO WORLD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        if (msg == "LED ON") {

            imageView1.setVisibility(imageView1.VISIBLE);
            imageView2.setVisibility(imageView2.INVISIBLE);

        }

        if (msg == "LED OFF") {
            imageView2.setVisibility(imageView2.VISIBLE);
            imageView1.setVisibility(imageView1.INVISIBLE);
        }

        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private void startactivity(Intent i) {

    }
}

    package com.example.nhx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class blinkMe extends Activity {
    Button ON;
    Button OFF;
    ImageView imageView1;
    ImageView imageView2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ON = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ON);
        OFF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OFF);
        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        ON.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                sendSMS("5556", "LED ON");
                OFF.setClickable(true);
                imageView1.setVisibility(imageView1.VISIBLE);
                imageView2.setVisibility(imageView2.INVISIBLE);

            }

            private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
                ON.setClickable(true);

            }
        });

        OFF.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                ON.setClickable(true);
                sendSMS("5554", "LED OFF");
                /* Intent i = new Intent(); */

                imageView2.setVisibility(imageView2.VISIBLE);
                imageView1.setVisibility(imageView1.INVISIBLE);

            }

            private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

In my application I have two buttons like on and off and two images overlapping each other,  red and green colour. When I click on button green image should come foreword and when I click off, red image should come foreword, along with it one message should be sent to predefined number when the button is clicked means two events takes place when the button is clicked 
1. corresponding image switches foreword 
2. message is sent to predefined number

Now the problem arises after sending message the intended receiver sends us message now based on the message received the image should automatically get changed  like if the receiver reply's  on then green image should come foreword  and if he reply's off then red image should come foreword.

Comment: Try using an ImageButton instead, it'll be much easier.

Comment: shark can you provide some example means what difference does it make whether you use image frame or image button. and can you provide some kind of example where some action is getting performed when a message is received.

Comment: Code please so we can get better idea